# CircleImageView only support image from xml src android

Tags: android, imageview

I am using [CircleImageView](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView) for populating circle image in my android application.But after using the sample project i found that image which is circled, set from the xml using the following code:-

```
<com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
    android:id="@+id/circleImgView"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:src="@drawable/image"
    app:border="true"
    app:border_color="@color/GrayLight"
    app:border_width="10"
    app:shadow="true" />
```

After that i tried to set image to this view from java. Image is successfully set but circle effect doesn't working.

```
   imgView = (CircularImageView)findViewById(R.id.circleImgView);
   imgView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image);
```

I need to set image programmatically using java. But it is not working by this way.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to set image programmatically from java using setBackgroundResource method. But when i use
imgView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image) the image remain unchange. The circle view effect not work.

Comment: 1 - Do you want to change te bg or the src? 2 - `R.drawable.image` is the very same as `@drawable/image` 3 - still unclear what are you trying to do... also note that **setBackgroundResource** is obsolete since JELLY_BEAN (use **setBackground** from API Level 16+)

Comment: Thank You Sir!
Got the solution. Using imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image) it works !

Comment: You're welcome, sir. So, it was the `src` you wanted to change. Mystery solved.